# Disable the scrolling by a submit button while NOT disabling PHP?

Tags: php, email, button, submit, forwarding

I would like to disable the scrolling upon clicking a submit button placed in a submission form while I still want to get PHP's email forwarding functionality associated with the button working.

I read this article and verified that the use of preventDefault() disables both the default behaviour of the submit button and the PHP code associated with the button:

[How do i stop a page from scrolling to the top when button clicked in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984330/how-do-i-stop-a-page-from-scrolling-to-the-top-when-button-clicked-in-php)

Please someone advise me how to achieve the both.

Answer (score 0):

First you just need to add a function like

```
form.onsubmit = function()
{
   // disable scroll code, see link below
};
```

here's a good answer how to disable the mouse scroll and other keys:

[How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)